# WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS enumeration class

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, usersession

I have to determine what state the user session is in. i.e if the the user is logged on and active or if the user is not logged on. To do this im using the function `WTSEnumerateSessions` and then I am checking the `WTS_SESSION_INFO`which is return from this function which has a state member.

According to the online documentation.

> WTSActive A user is logged on to the WinStation
>
> WTSDisconnected
>   The WinStation is active but the client is disconnected.

The problem is that im currently logged onto my system but the state returned for my current session is `WTSDisconnected` im expecting the state to be `WTSActive` is there any reason as to why this is happening?

Code below

```
PWTS_SESSION_INFO pSessionInfo(nullptr);
    DWORD countOfSessions(0);
    DWORD sessionIndex(0);

    if (WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,     // local machine
        0,                              // reserved, must be zero
        1,                              // Version, must be one
        &pSessionInfo,
        &countOfSessions) == FALSE)
    {

        return false;
    }

    if (countOfSessions == 0 || !pSessionInfo)
    {
        return false;
    }

    const DWORD currentSession = GetRealSessionID(CurrentSession); //This case we are in session 0
    for (; sessionIndex < countOfSessions; ++sessionIndex)
    {
        WTS_SESSION_INFO& sessionInfo = pSessionInfo[sessionIndex];
        if (currentSession == sessionInfo.SessionId)
        {
            if (sessionInfo.State == WTSActive)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


    return false;
```

Thanks

Comment: We can't see your code. For all we know it has mistakes in it. For instance, maybe you are not checking for errors and you end up reading uninitialized data. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have added my code

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. I'm seeing `WTSDisconnected` for session 0, which is reasonable, and `WTSActive` for the console session. We can only guess what `GetRealSessionID` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense. The most likely explanation is that `currentSession` is being assigned a value of `0`, which is the session ID for the non-interactive isolated session in which services run.